# How to Select Single Row from a Table in SQL Using Multiple Criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table_A with data extracted from service cloud (salesforce) about customers (name, email, customer_nr, etc), but for the same email I have more than one entry. This happens due to different reasons, but I want to select only the row that follows a certain rule, because I can only have one email per person.

**Table_A:**

| Email | CustomerType | First_Name | Last_Name | Owner_FirstName | Owner_LastName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| testA@email.com | CustomerServiceAdd | NULL | NULL | Patricia | Portela |
| testA@email.com | RegisteredSubscriber | John | Smith | User | SCCIntegration |

So basically when I group by the email and having count(*)>1, it needs to follows these **rules**:

1. I want that when there is more than one entry for the same email, it selects the row where CONCAT([Owner.FirstName],[Owner.LastName])='**UserSCCIntegration**'
2. When for the same email, there's more than one row where CONCAT([Owner.FirstName],[Owner.LastName])='**UserSCCIntegration**', then should be selected the row where SFCC_Customer_Number__pc (this column was not selected for table_A, but it exists in my datatable) is not NULL.

I tried using a CASE WHEN but didn't manage to produce any result, so I am wondering how should the query be created and if using CASE WHEN clause is the right way to go.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's a lot easier for us to help you fix your code if we can see it and have a minimal, complete example: DDL, sample data and expected results.

Comment: @Stu it doesn't because on that case the user only wants to select the top 1 row. I want to select according to a criteria, so that when when I group by the email and having count(*)>1, it should be considered the row where CONCAT([Owner.FirstName],[Owner.LastName])='UserSCCIntegration'

Comment: When for the same email, there's more than one row where CONCAT([Owner.FirstName],[Owner.LastName])='UserSCCIntegration', then should be selected the row where SFCC_Customer_Number__pc (this column was not selected for table_A, but it exists in my datatable) is not NULL.

Comment: @HABO thank you, but unfortunately I don't have the code. I tried using CASE WHEN but without success. I only know what are my conditions but I'm struggling to implement them.

Comment: You misunderstand that post. The answers there show how to select the top 1 per group, you just need to define your group and ordering correctly. In this case as @JoelCoehoorn shows, the grouping is `Email` and the ordering is a complex `CASE` expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `row_number()` windowing function. First add this to the `SELECT` list:

```
row_number() over (PARTITION BY Email 
                   ORDER BY case when CONCAT([Owner.FirstName],[Owner.LastName])='UserSCCIntegration' then 0 else 1 end,
                            case when SFCC_Customer_Number__pc is not null then 0 else 1 end
                  ) rn
```

Then nest the whole query in another `SELECT` statement and filter based on the new `rn` column:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  -- Original query goes here

) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

This assumes you've already added the necessary `JOIN`s to make the `SFCC_Customer_Number__pc` value available.